# Asyncstorage in Redux action

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use my access token (stored in Asyncstorage) in a Redux action. This is my code:

```
export function fetchData() {
  const endpoint = 'someEndpoint.com';
  let accessToken = '';
  myAccessToken().then((token) => {
    accessToken = token;
  });

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getData());
    axios.get(endpoint, { headers: { 'access-token': accessToken } })
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(getDataFailure(error));
    });
  };
}
```

```
const myAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
    const retrievedItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    return retrievedItem;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

But fetching of the key is obviously async, I'm not sure on how to use the accessToken in the API call. I'm not allowed to do something like this:

```
export function fetchData() {
  const endpoint = 'someEndpoint.com';
  myAccessToken().then((token) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(getData());
      axios.get(endpoint, { headers: { 'access-token': token } })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(getDataFailure(error));
      });
    };
  });
}
```

My Store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import app from './reducers';

export default function configureStore() {
  return createStore(app, applyMiddleware(thunk));
}
```

**Update**

[In the end](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVTXPUF4Oz4) I did it a little bit different, In my `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then((accessToken) => {
      this.setState({ accessToken });
      this.props.fetchData(accessToken);
    });
  }
```

Thanks, Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `redux-thunk` library for asynchronous updates of the redux state. It's easy to configure in the store.js file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Then, I would implement it like this:

```
export function fetchData() {
  return async function(dispatch) {
     const endpoint = 'someEndpoint.com';
     const accessToken = await myAccessToken();
     try {
        const response = await axios.get(endpoint, { headers: { 'access-token': accessToken } });
        return dispatch(getDataSuccess(response.data));
     } catch (error) {
        return dispatch(getDataFailure(error));
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @alexgomez0120! I tried your suggestion, which results into the following error: `error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. (I already had `redux-thunk` implemented)

Comment: @KevinEtore I have edited my answer, assuming that `fetchData()` is an action creator that returns a function as an action.

Comment: Take also into account that `getDataSuccess()` and `getDataFailure()` functions should return an object with the type of the redux action like: `{type:  "FETCH_SUCCESS", data: {} }`

Comment: thanks for your help! I updated my question with the current solution!